# $P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>X_{(3)})$ for order statistic

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I am trying to solve this problem for when $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent $U(0,1)$-distributed random variables. The joint density function should then be given by

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)= 
\begin{cases}
6, \; 0<x_1<x_2<x_3<1\\
0, \text{ else}
\end{cases}$$

My idea was to split the probability into different cases for when $X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}$ is gretaer than or smaller than 1, in the following way

$$P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>X_{(3)})=P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>X_{(3)}|X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>1)P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>1)+P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>X_{(3)}|X_{(1)}+X_{(2)} \leq 1)P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)} \leq 1)$$

However, I run into trouble when trying to compute this, since i get that the probabilities of both of these cases are 0.

$$P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}>1)=\int_0^1\int_{1-x_2}^{x_2}6dx_1dx_2=\int_0^112x_2-6dx_2=0$$

$$P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)} \leq 1)=\int_0^1\int_{x_1}^{1-x_1}6dx_2dx_1=\int_0^16-12x_2dx_1=0$$

I think there might be something wrong with my integral bounds but I'm not sure what. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It might be of interest to note that the probability-preserving transformation $$(X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)})\to (X_{(3)}-X_{(2)},X_{(3)}-X_{(1)}, X_{(3)})$$ preserves the order.  Consequently, $$\Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\gt X_{(3)}) = \Pr([X_{(3)}-X_{(2)}] + [X_{(3)}-X_{(1)}]\gt X_{(3)}) = \Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\lt X_{(3)})$$ (the last equality is just algebra). Since this distribution is continuous, $\Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}= X_{(3)})=0.$ Thus, $$1=\Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\gt X_{(3)})+\Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\lt X_{(3)})=2\Pr(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\gt X_{(3)}).$$

Comment: Since you're practicing multiple integration, try to see how the answer can be expressed as $$6\int_0^1\,\mathrm{d}x_3\int_0^{x_3}\,\mathrm{d}x_2\int_0^{\min(x_2,x_3-x_2)}\,\mathrm{d}x_1.$$ The inner integral (over $x_1$) breaks into two integrals, according to which of $x_2$ and $x_3-x_2$ is the larger, that upon a simple integration by parts are seen to be equal.  This makes the calculation straightforward.

Comment: I am curious to see how you evaluate $\mbox{Pr} \left(X_{(1)} + X_{(2)}>X_{(3)} | X_{(1)} + X_{(2)} \le 1 \right).$

Comment: @whuber any chance you could show me how to evaluate the probability in the previous comment?

Comment: @whuber that's a neat way of solving it. Thanks!

Comment: @user277126 Computing $\Pr\left(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\gt X_{(3)}\mid X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\le1\right)$ comes down to finding the chances of the conditioning event $X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\le 1$ (which obviously is $1/2$) and of their conjunction, then dividing the latter by the former. But noticing these conditions imply $X_{(1)}\le 1/2$ and using $0\le X_{(1)}\le X_{(2)}\le X_{(3)}\le 1,$ compute$$\Pr\left(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\gt X_{(3)}\text{ and }X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\le1\right)=6\int_0^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x_1\int_{x_1}^{1-x_1}\mathrm{d}x_2\int_{x_2}^{x_1+x_2}\mathrm{d}x_3=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must derive the joint distribution of $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}$ from the full joint distribution.  This is given by
$$
f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}} (x_1, x_2) = \int_{x_2}^1 6 ~\mbox{d} x_3 = 6(1-x_2) \mbox{I}(0<x_1<x_2<1).
$$
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr} \left[X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}<1\right] &=& 6\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-x_2) \mbox{I}(0<x_1<x_2<1)\mbox{I}(x_1+x_2<1) ~\mbox{d} x_1 \mbox{d} x_2.
\end{eqnarray*}
To simplify the indicator functions, draw a picture with $x_2$ as the $y$-axis and $x_1$ as the $x$-axis.  You will find that this denotes a region such that $x_1<x_2<1-x_1$ and $0<x_1<.5$.  Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr} \left[X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}<1\right] &=& 6\int_0^{.5}\int_{x_1}^{1-x_1}(1-x_2) ~ \mbox{d} x_2 \mbox{d} x_1 \\
&=& 3\int_0^{.5}(1-2x_1) ~\mbox{d} x_1 \\
&=& \frac{3}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Great answer! I really like this one!